# Granting LIST permissions on a subset of an S3 bucket

Tags: security, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket in S3 that contains files for a number of users, like so:

```
mybucket
  /user1/file1.jpg
  /user1/file2.jpg
  /user2/doc1.jpg
  /user2/doc2.jpg
```

I am using the S3 REST API to grant a user privileges to POST to their subfolder in the S3 bucket.  The path to post (for example, "user1/") is included in the signature, so the user cannot POST to another user's subfolder.

I want to use the S3 REST API to grant a user privileges to GET the file contents in their subfolder as well.  However, according to the documentation here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

The URL can filter the contents of the bucket, like so:

```
GET /?prefix=user1 HTTP/1.1
```

But the string to sign does not have the prefix:

```
GET\n
\n
\n
Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:42:41 +0000\n
/bucket/
```

This means that user1 can modify the URL and look at other user2's subdirectory contents (!?!?).

Is there a way to limit what file contents are listed, or do I have to create a separate bucket for each user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could sign the GET URLs with credentials for different IAM users, each with privilege for just the paths you want them to see.